# I'm creating a function for the nth_lowest number in a list and I don't know why it's not working

Tags: python, function, math

```
nums = [324,456,4645,34,5,56,76]

def nth_lowest(list, nlowest = 1):
    t = []
    for i in range(nlowest):
        t.append(min(list))
        list.remove(min(list))
    print(min(t))


nth_lowest(nums, 4)
```

The code keeps returning 5 which is the minimum of the list, no matter what I put for the second argument

Comment: This is because you are printing `min(t)` which will always be the minimum element. You can use `t[-1]` instead. A better way is to sort the list and print the nth element.

Comment: `t[-1]` will return the greatest numerical object in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```py
nums = [324, 456, 4645, 34, 5, 56, 76]

def nth_lowest(list, nlowest=1):
    print(sorted(list)[nlowest-1])


nth_lowest(nums, 4)
```

You keep returning the minimum value of the list through `min()`. You also rather not want to use a builtin function `list` as a variable name.

You can also compress these lines:

```py
for i in range(nlowest):
        t.append(min(list))
        list.remove(min(list))
```

into

```py
t = sorted(list)
```

Using `sorted(list)` sorts it from low to high, and takes the index `nlowest - 1` which is the first value for `nlowest = 1`, second for `nlowest = 2`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the shortened and easier to read version, I didn't even realize how complicated I made this problem

Comment: Happy to help! Also `sorted()` sorts integers by low to high and strings in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

```py
nums = [324,456,4645,34,5,56,76]

def nth_lowest(list, nlowest = 1):
    t = []
    for i in range(nlowest):
        t.append(min(list))
        list.remove(min(list))
    # You were printing minimum from "t"      
    # print(min(t))     
    # but instead you planned to print lowest from the "list"      
    # use      

    print(min(list))  

    # from which you are removing the lowest number for 'n' times.


nth_lowest(nums, 4)
# Also in the 'for' loop you are removing lowest letter for number 
#specified by the user let's say 4 which will leave the 5th lowest 
#in the list and that will be printed try changin
```